# Scrapy new Request URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Good night, I'm having some difficulty in managing Scrapy requests

My Spider works as follows:

I use the parse function > 
 
I connect to the database > 
I start a loop for each item in the database list >
each page has a captcha that is broken by a bypass, I use post and get for that > 
 I access a form and I handle the information.

What happens is that for each item is necessary a new query, only that my code is repeating the same captcha and the same page, how do I it "refresh" the page every new query?

```
def parse(self, response):
    conn = None
    try:
        # read connection parameters
        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
        # create a cursor
        # execute a statement
        # display the PostgreSQL database server version
        print("--- Start crawl ---")
        print("Get ...")

        # Current Database ID
        cur.execute()
        print(cur.rowcount)
        row = cur.fetchone()
        count = 1
        while row is not None:
            
            print("Count: (%s/%s)" % (count, cur.rowcount))
         
            captcha

            if captcha: # Captcha code                   
                yield FormRequest.from_response(
                    response,
                    formdata={}                            
                    callback=self.start_scraping
                )
            else:
                print("Captcha not Found")

            row = cur.fetchone()
            count = count + 1

        # close the communication with the PostgreSQL
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
            print('Database connection closed.')
```

Comment: you can use cookie jar in meta so that cookies don't get mix across requests.

Comment: Hassan, How I make this?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider